# 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Visibility\Condition does not exist

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, magento-2.2.1

I get the above error while upgrading from Magento 2.1.8 to Magento 2.2.1

> ```
> 2 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Visibility\Condition does not
> ```
>
> exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was My theme files did not have the proper files for patch since the base was different, so had to redo the whole theme installation proccess

Answer (score 1):

Issues like the one you mentioned can have several reasons. The following command sequence will check the dependencies and regenerates the code. It might be too much commands to fix your particular problem but with the information you added to your question, it might be the best solution for a "quick fix":

## Enter your Magento 2 working dir

`cd MAGENTO_ROOT`

## Remove generated code pieces to make sure we have a clean workspace

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/di/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* vendor`

## Install composer dependencies

`composer install`

## Compile DI Classes

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

## Compile Static Files

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

## Set Permissions

`chmod -R www-data:www-data && find app/code pub/static app/etc var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed vendor \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} \; && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento`

## In a single "liner"

`(cd MAGENTO_ROOT && rm -Rf var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* var/di/* generated/code/* vendor && commposer install && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && chmod -R www-data:www-data && find app/code pub/static app/etc var/generation var/di var/view_preprocessed vendor \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} \; && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php && chmod u+x bin/magento) || echo "Whooops, that failed..."`